# Check if number is in an array an generate new number if it is

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple script to create a random number. The intent of the script is to ultimately cache each random number in an array and then loop through this array when generating new numbers to see if the previous one had already been used. If it has been used then the script would continue looping until a number is created that is not in the array, and then return *that* number. I wrote the code below and the logic is simple enough but I don't know why it works when launched  *sometimes* and then *blows the stack at other times* without returning a number.

```
var oldNumbs = [1,2,3,4,6,7] // dummy data
var randomNumb = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) +1);


function checkIfInArray(value, array) {

  if(array.indexOf(value) > -1){
    randomNumb = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) +1);
    checkIfInArray(value, array)

  }
  else{
    return randomNumb
  }
}

console.log(checkIfInArray(randomNumb,oldNumbs)); /* sometimes returns a number not in the array and sometimes blows the stack. It mostly blows the stack. */
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple mistake it is. You need to pass `randomNumb`  instead of `value` since `randomNumb` is the new random number you generated.

```
checkIfInArray(randomNumb , array)
```

Comment: Thanks, Now I get undefined in place of the stack blowing. It works ... then undefined...it works...then undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'undefined' comes because you don't return anything if the number is already in the array.

```
function checkIfInArray(value, array) {

  if(array.indexOf(value) > -1){
    var randomNumb = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) +1);
    value = checkIfInArray(randomNumb, array);

  } 
  return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this your actual code because you've passing value in to the recursive call to checkIfInArray, this just passes the same random number over and over again, if that number was already in the array it crashes, change it to randomNumb and you should be fine.

Comment: I appreciate the "is this your actual code" comment. I was tempted to respond with my own naive nonchalant condescending reply but I'm not going to do that. Thank you and I appreciate your help. It now returns undefined instead of blowing the stack.